# Use all subnet IDs in a given VPC with DBSubnetGroup in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to figure out how I'd use the DBSubnetGroup resource in Cloudformation to grab every subnet under the configured VPC. Here's my code as of now:

```
  DBSubnetGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup'
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
      SubnetIds:
        - subnet-54b7e96a
        - subnet-68eb3125
        - subnet-744c4613
```

I'd like to avoid having to specify exactly which subnet IDs to use in my VPC.

Comment: You want to automatically populate the list of subsets with ALL of the subnets  in your VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is **no such functionality** in CloudFormation (CFN) to query a VPC and get ids of all its subnets.

If you require this, you would have to develop your own [AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html). The resource would be in the form of a **lambda function** which would take the VPC Id as an input argument, and then, using AWS SDK, query the VPC for its subnets. The subnets found would be returned to your template for use in `AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup`.

Comment: Even if there was even a unidirectional way to say `SubnetIds: *` would be nice

Comment: @aphexlog Yes, but sadly such function does not exist yet. You can only do this for AZs using [Fn::GetAZs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getavailabilityzones.html).

Comment: So, I started using the `List` type param and it does pretty much what I'm looking for:  

```TestParam:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Description: List of EC2 subnet IDs```
I just need to see if I can now figure out how to get a list of subnets in a given VPC, rather than just a list of all subnets

Comment: @aphexlog I already told you how - using custom resource. There is no other way, unless you want to hardcode them, or pass programatically as parameters to your template.